# Changing the text.ForeColor of all matched instances using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, textbox

I have a *multi-lined* `TextBox`. I have also an `Input` box used in specifying a *Regex* string that is used in formatting the text that is entered in the `TextBox`.

`Regex.Replace` replaces strings. What I want is to apply some styling to the found matched as using *Bold*, *Italic* and change its *ForeColor*.

For Example:

Text in `TextBox`:

> Change all text in the multi-lined
>   text box that matches the text inside
>   the  input box's text box

String in Input Box/Regex:

> text

And I have:

```
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
```

The desired result:

> Change all **text** in the multi-lined
>   **text** box that matches the **text** inside the input box's **text** box

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `RichTextBox` for this. First use the RegEx to find the indexes of the sub strings and then use `SelectionStart` and `SelectionEnd` to select that text in the RTB and `SelectionFont` and `SelectionColor` to make it bold and colored.

Comment: @sir Dahiel Hilgarth: I using a multi-lined text box sir

Comment: @gibz357: I know. But you can't color text in a normal TextBox.

Comment: Can it still change it to Bold or/and Italic?

Comment: @gibz357: No. As I said, you need to use a RichTextBox.